# Designing a scenario where a primary key could be of two types

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtypes

I have a table: `all_info`, where it holds the users identification. The `id` of this table can be of two types (just one **or** another, never both), suppose: `int` and `varchar`, but one table can't have two primary keys, and **a composite one wouldn't solve my problem**.

So, I can't do this:

```
+--------------------+
| all_info           |
+--------------------+
| PK id1 varchar(50) |
| PK id2 int         |
| ...                |
+--------------------+
```

Then, I created two others tables: `unique_info1` and `unique_info2` with the primary keys of the types that I needed, add some informations for the specific types of users, and made relations with the table: `all_info`, that holds the rest of the users informations (that both types share).

With this scheme, I could relate `unique_info1` and `unique_info2` with every other table, but I would need to create two columns in every one of them to establish that relationship. To solve this, I had created an artificial primary key in `all_info` to make all posterior relationships.

Now, it looks like this:

Obs: `FK uniq1_id varchar(50)` and `FK uniq2_id int(10)` are unique and nullable.

```
+--------------------+    +--------------------+    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
| unique_info1       |    | unique_info2       |    | all_info                |    | other_table             |
+--------------------+    +--------------------+    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
| PK id varchar(50)  |    | PK id int(10)      |    | PK id int(10)           |    | ...                     |
| ...                |    | ...                |    | ...                     |    | ...                     |
| ...                |    | ...                |    | FK uniq1_id varchar(50) |    | ...                     |
| ...                |    | ...                |    | FK uniq2_id int(10)     |    | FK all_id int(10)       |
+--------------------+    +--------------------+    +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
```

The thing is: that's the best approach, or should I change the plan?

For examples:

1. Choose other information to be the id of the users, where all will have the same type, and add all specific info of the users to that hole table?

   - This would result in a lot of `null` columns for each user.
2. Create two completely different tables for the two types of users?

   - This would result in redundant info.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Are you saying that there are two types of users? If so, which columns are common and which are specific to each type? Or, do both types have id_1 and id_2?

Comment: They have just one or another. Never both. I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: I question whether vertical partitioning makes sense here.  Few applications will have millions of users, so I doubt there's a strong performance reason.  You're creating some real complexity and room for inconsistent data this way; are you sure it's necessary?  `NULL` fields are not evil.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - No, i'm not sure. So, you would vote for my first example, where i have to choose other info to be the pk and have a unique table for all users?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do.  A synthetic ID rarely hurts, and in this case it's significantly simpler.  I'm a little confused about exactly what you're asking - it sounds like you really want opinions on whether to partition this table, and it's not really about PKs.  If so, then I think @david25272's answer is right on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

Also search for `super type/subtype` here and on the SO.

Comment: I'll have to study this diagram, after i'll give you feedback. Thanks. Just a detail: your word "here" was meant to be a link?

Comment: @RafaelBarros; here on DBA.SE site.

Comment: Oh, ok. I've been thinking and looks like the things that i haven't understood on the diagram doesn't influence the big picture of the idea. It looks like your way is much more obvious, and that i was thinking upside down. Thank you again.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic How about the ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram) ? I have case like this, but I don't understand how to make its ERD? Could your tell me please?

Comment: @Ayuktia It's probably too late now, but you may find [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644) of help in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

If *all* users have both types of ID you could make `id2` the primary key, and build a `unique not null` index for `id1` (assuming that both types of ID have to be unique).  Only `id2` could be used as a foreign key in this scheme, but you could always retrieve `id1` with a simple join.

If not all users have both types of ID you could make *two* `unique` (but nullable) indexes, and add a third column to be the primary key (something like `id3 integer identity primary key` might be suitable).  You would then use `id3` in other tables as a foreign key.

Comment: Your second idea corresponds to my scheme. And that is what is already implemented: `FK uniq1_id varchar(50)` and `FK uniq2_id int(10)` are unique and nullable; your `id3 integer identity primary key` is my `PK id int(10) [AI]`. I will edit the question to be more clear. So, i suppose you agree with my design?