# Is this a sane model for a network provisioning system?

Tags: database-design, network

I'm sketching out a model for a network setup, where I have the following conditions:

1. There are multiple nodes which contains a number of switches each.
2. Each switch has multiple services, which may or may not have a rate limiting.
3. Each service is identified by a VLAN ID (VID), which is different on each switch per node.
4. VID cannot be re-used for other services across switches, but it is permitted to re-use the VID for the same service on switches on a different node.
5. The rate limiting for each service may be overridden by the profile assigned to the CPE.
6. A CPE can have any number of ports, each with its own service, and possibly rate-limit. VID and default rate-limit is determined by service, as noted above.

Example on the service-switch-VID restrictions: The "Internet" service has VID 1 on switch 1, and VID 11 on switch 2 for node #1, and #2. But VID 21 and 31 for switch 1 and 2 on node #3

[image: The model]

Please let me know if you need any additional information. Almost 3am here, so I might have forgotten something.

**Update:** Fixed the list, and updated the model to reflect the changes I've highlighted in my first comment. Also noticed a missing FK relation, between `cpe` and cpe_port`, which I've added.

Comment: Quick update: I found one area which was bothering me, while adding data to the database. I thus dropped the (poorly named) `switch_profile` table, and replaced it with a M2M relation between `vlan` and `profile`.

Comment: Good question. I would like to share my thoughts and propose a data model in an answer, but I want to clarify certain points in order to avoid misunderstandings as far as possible. **(1)** Is the entity `Profile` used to represent a `Person` in your model? **(2)** What is the format used to define the `VLan` identifier, is it just a random number? **(3)** What is the meaning that the entity `Node` has in your model? **(4)** Is a `Node` really different than a `CPE`? **(5)** Do they have attributes in common? **(6)**  What attributes uniquely identify a `Node` and a `CPE`?

Comment: **(5)** Are `CPEs` the only kind of equipment allowed to use a `Port` and a `Service`? **(6)** Do you follow a convention for numbering CPE `Ports`? **(6)** A `Port` is always fixed to **exactly one** `Service`, right? **(7)** Examples of services are: Email, print, filesharing, voice over IP, etc., is this correct? **(8)** How many `Services` are you planning to store in your database? **(9)** How do you uniquely identify a `Service`?

Comment: **(10)** How do you uniquely identify a `Switch`? **(11)** Is a `Switch` always related to **exactly one** `Node` at **a specific point** in time or, can it be related to **multiple** `Nodes` at the **same time**?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The answers to your questions are:

Comment: **(1)** It specifies a speed profile, like "10/1 mbit". Basically a collection of specific (default) rate limits for a service. **(2)** It's a VLAN tag ID, basically a randomly picked number. **(3)** A node is a location for a collection of switches; A room, building, town or whatever that geographically identifies that group. **(4)** Yes, a CPE is a customer unit that provides the internet connection to said customer; Modem, switch, etc. **(5)** No attributes in common. **(6)** For CPE it's the MAC, and for a node it's its location on the map.

Comment: **(5)** Yes. **(6)** Starting at 1, counting up to whatever number of ports said unit has available. **(6)** Correct, one port == one service. **(7)** Basically, though more general. Like Internet, VOIP, IPTV etc. **(8)** Very few, only 4 defined so far. **(9)** By what VLAN it uses, and in some cases the rate limit as well. For example: VOIP is internet, with a very low rate limit. While IPTV is in a whole different VLAN. **(10)** By its MAC address. **(11)** Only one node at a time; Physics demands such. ;)
-------
Let me know if there's more you're wondering about. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. I haven’t noticed ’till now that I numbered in a terrible way my questions, but I’m sure they’re going to help us to create a good data structure, since it’s fundamental to know the contextual meaning of the things that are relevant in a particular scenario in order to understand the data and, therefore, model it. This is a good oportunity to “refresh” a couple of subjects from my networking courses, by the way, ha ha. Great responses from you, I can start working on a data model now but, in the meantime, I want to understand some other things better:

Comment: **(a)** How many `Locations` you plan to store in your database? **(b)** I assume that a specific `Node` is never going to change the particular `Location` that it belongs to, am I right? **(c)** What are the meanings of the attributes `Location.Short`, `Node.Short` and `Switch.Short`? **(d)** I assume that the attributes `CPEPort.RateLimit` and `Service.RateLimit` have a similar meaning to the `Profile` entity, is this correct? **(e)** Does a `Switch` have a particular `Port` defined for every `CPE`?  **(f)** Do `Switches` have in general a specific `Service` or `Port` fixed for them? Cheers.

Comment: **(g)** So, according to you comment update,  there’s a **many-to-many** relationship between `VLan` and `Profile`, i.e. a `VLan` can have one to many `Profiles` (speed) at the same time, is this correct? As I understand it, this most have an effect in some way to `Services` or `CPEs` and, of course to `Switches` so, **(h)** could you expand on this points?

Comment: **(a)** Not too many. However, you have a point and I should probably change it to a SMALLINT. Just to be on the safe side. **(b)** I don't foresee that happening, no. Though, there might be more nodes added to a location in the future. **(c)** An abbreviation of their full name, basically a human-compatible primary key. **(d)** Yes. The `Service` entry is the first default value, which might be overridden by the `Profile` entry. Both of which can be manually overriden, and the final result stored in the `CPEPort` entry.

Comment: **(e)** A switch may have more ports than CPEs, but only one CPE per port and no more CPEs than ports physically present on the switch. **(f)** No, and not really. Services are specified by the VLAN, and ports are just the physical ports on the actual switch. **(g)** Yes that is correct. I found a discrepancy between the model above, and the actual data as I've described it in my answers to you. I found that the actual switch had nothing to do with what profile was available, as this is already determined by the switch-VLAN relation. The VLAN determines which profiles can be used, nothing else

Comment: Ignore my comment about changing the type, in my answer **(a)**. For some reason I though I had defined it as a TINYINT.

Comment: Updated my question with an updated image, to show exactly what I have at this point in time. Also fixed the list, as it was annoying me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Understanding of the specifications and proposed data model

We have mantained very productive interactions via comments, I have read your question carefully and examinined your diagram closely, so I have prepared the following assertions that I consider relevant in order to describe my current understanding of your scenario and, therefore, share my personal approach to such:

- A `Node` lodges **one-to-many** `Switches`.
- A `Switch` forwards data to **one-to-many** `Services` (employing **one** particular `VLAN` in **each** data forward).
- A `Switch` provides **one-to-many** `Services` to **one-to-many** `CPEs` (employing **one** specific `VLAN` in **each** provisioning). Or, put another way, a `CPE` is provided with **one-to-many** `Services` by **one-to-many** `Switches` (using **one** specific `VLAN` in **each** provisioning).
- A `CPE` is classified by **one** `SpeedProfile`.
- A `CPE` is set with **one** `Port` in oder to receive **one specific**  `Service`.
- A `CPE` is set with **one** `Port` in oder to receive data from **one specific** `Switch`.
- A `Customer` (**either one** `Organization` **or one** `Person`) receives **one-to-many** `Services` via **one** `CPE`.

From such collection of assertions, I have derived (and uploaded as a .PDF document to Dropbox) the following…

- [**Network Provisioning Preliminary Data Model**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pehufk56knoujs/Network%20Provisioning%20Preliminary%20Data%20Model.pdf).

***Note**: It is necessary to point out that some of these assertions (or parts of specific ones) have been identified as inaccurate or erroneous, as mentioned below in the section entitled **Subsequent conclusions**.*

As you can see in said [**IDEF1X**](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm) data model, I consider that `CPEService` is the “core” entity, so to speak, since this is where I think that the relationships between `CPEs` and `Services`, `Switches` or `VLANs` take effect.

It is very important to mention that, if I understand your specifications well, there is a “**three way**” relationship in which the entities `Service`, `Switch` and `VLAN` are involved. That is why I have modelled **(a)** the association between `Switch` and `VLAN` in a specific **many-to-many** relationship, **(b)** the association between `Service` and `VLAN` in another particular **many-to-many** relationship, and **(c)** another **many-to-many** relationship called `SwitchVLANService`, where the “connection” between these three entities actually takes place.

I have used **natural** PRIMARY KEYS as much as has been possible, in order to capture the **meaning** of every prime attribute and make it more evident not only in its original entities, but also when it **migrates** to related ones. If you feel comfortable with my proposed model, it will be more easy for you to determine the stability of each one of such KEYS, and decide if you keep them or replace them with different ones, since you are, of course, involved in the actual context where the database is going to be used.

## Subsequent conclusions

By virtue of comparing our models, discussing the important subjects and clarifiying the pending points via comments, we have have been able to confirm most of the things that you have already defined in your model:

- The “three way” relationship between `Service`, `Switch` and `VLAN` that I proposed in my preliminary is totally unnecessary, since what it is actually relevant in your context is stroring only what `Service` is broadcast by a particular `VLAN`. In this manner, a `Service` is related to a `Switch` by means of its association with a `VLAN`.
- The `Service.RateLimit`, the `SpeedProfiles` defined for a specific `VLAN` and the `CPEPort.RateLimit` are all necessary, and you will manually decide which speed is set for a particular set of entities, since you have determined an overriding order for this aspectt.
- `CPEPorts` are not directly related to `Switches`, but `CPEPorts` have a direct relationship with `VLANs`, since you have to set a specific `CPEPort` to receive a given `Service` that is supplied by a particular `VLAN`. In this way, as you have pointed out via comments, it is necessary to ponder the possiblity of dropping the `Service - CPEport` relationship that you have presented in your diagram.
- The stability of the used PRIMARY KEYS has been identified.

[**This Network Provisioning Data model**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/amtkqhzsmlpq6z0/Network%20Provisioning%20Data%20Model.pdf) (also uploaded as a .PDF document to Dropbox), which is based on yours and also on the series of deliberations that we have kept over the last weeks, depicts these conclusions.

## The `Party` entity

I have included the `Party`<sup>**[1]**</sup> entity in the data model since I think that it can be very useful to provide a means to represent both `Organizations` and `Persons` as a single entity, while also keeping their particular attributes in two corresponding separate entities. This scenario is an occurrence of what is commonly referred as **supertype-subtype cluster** (an **exclusive** one, in this case) in which `Party` has been defined as the subertype, and `Organization` and `Person` as its subtypes. You may find [**this answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92065/help-with-a-scenario-of-music-groups-and-members-in-erd-design/102069#102069) of help as an introductory resource about this kind of structures.

Thus, your following comment provides a good oportunity for describing its usage:

> I quite like the Party table, though I don't think MySQL supports a compound FK in a single column? I'll, most likely, use a single table for both types of customers. Might also use two child tables, to contain the different info for each type of customer. With a 1-0 relation to the customer table.

These are very relevant points that you have brought to the discussion since, in accordance to the structure depicted in the new data model, it is not necessary to use a compound FOREIGN KEY in a single column, because `Organization.OrganizationId` and `Person.PersonId` are PRIMARY KEYS that, at the same time, serve as FOREIGN KEYS that draw their values from a corresponding row contained in `Party.PartyId`. This is an example of what Dr. E. F. Codd defined as **Primary Keys on a Common Domain**<sup>**[2]**</sup>.

This way, as you have already skillfully determined, you can use a single table for storing the data pertaining to the role played by a particular `Party` (`Organization` or `Person`) as a `Customer`, so I have included the latter entity in the model. For instance, suppose that the `MaximumOverdue` for customers will be arrranged on an individual basis, so this datum should be stored in the `Customer` table. It is also worth mentioning that the `Customer.CustomerId` PRIMARY KEY column expresses the **role name** assingned to `Party.PartyId` in this specific entity and, as such, `CustomerId` always takes its values from the last-mentioned column.

#### Implementation

The follwing are some important aspects that must be taken into account when implementing **exclusive** supertype-subtypes relationships:

- Each supertype row must always have one corresponding subtype row, that is, there should not be a single supertype row without one subtype counterpart stored in the database. This means that, in this particular scenario, you should make sure that there is not a single `Party` row without an `Organization` (or `Person`) row.
- Every supertype occurrence must only be complemented by the correct subtype
  instance, i.e., the value contained in the subtype **discriminator attribute** (which is `Party.PartyTypeCode`<sup>**[3]**</sup> in this case) has to be correct for the respective subtype row, and there should be no chance for a supertype to be supplemented by one row of the wrong subtype. In other words, you should create a method in order to assure that, when you have a `Party` that contains a `PartyTypeCode` value that indicates that such `Party` is an `Organization`, it is only complemented by a row contained in the `Organization` table, and never by a row contained in the `Person` table.

In order to cover these aspects in your database, I would highly recommend you inserting every supertype-subtype relationship instance inside a transaction.

## Notes

<sub>1. A **party** is a person or group of persons (or *people*) that compose a **single entity** in a [**legal sense**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_%28law%29), so this term is useful to represent either an `Organization` or a `Person` in this particular business domain.</sub>

<sub>2. Codd, E. F. (Jan. 1990). Introduction to Version 2 of the Relational Model. In *The Relational Model for Database Management: Version 2* (pp. 25-26). Boston, MA, USA: Addison-Wesley</sub>

<sub>3. Since a party has only two possible subtypes, you can remove the `PartyType` entity and the subsequent `Party.PartyTypeCode` column, and then handle the `Party` subtype discriminator by means of a BIT column, which you could possibly denote as `IsOrganization` or `IsPerson`.</sub>

Comment: You've certainly have gone beyond anything I could hope for on this one, and I would like to offer you my greatest gratitude for all of your assistance and work. I think we've pretty much nailed this one, as both our models are similar. Except for the minor alteration in dropping the abovementioned relationship. So I think it's safe to say that this one has been answered fully and comprehensively. :D ** Should you need someone to give you an in-depth analysis of/help on some PHP code, just let me know and I'll be more than happy to offer you my time and knowledge. Least I could do. :)